# Compare two strings and return different stretch

Tags: javascript

I have two strings like these:

```
var str1 = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
var str2 = "ipsum dolor";
```

And I'm trying to compare them and get, as result, an array with everything that doesn't match this comparation and the match! One for the beggining and the other one for the ending.

E.g: In this case above, the return should be an array like this:

```
result[0] //should keep the begining **"lorem "** (with the blank space after word)

result[1] // should keep the ending **" sit amet"** (with the blank space before word)

result[2] // should keep the match **"ipsum dolor"**
```

All I got was an elegant solution posted by @[Mateja Petrovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8809024/mateja-petrovic). But I can get this values separately.

Just like this:

```js
const A = "ipsum dolor"
const B = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
const diff = (diffMe, diffBy) => diffMe.split(diffBy).join('')
const C = diff(B, A)
console.log(C) // jumps over the lazy dog.
```

I'm really stuck! Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you remove `.join('')` from the solution you have, you'll get an Array like `["lorem ", " sit amet"]`. One question though, what do you want to happen if the substring is contained multiple times in the other? (if that's a possibility in your use case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const diff = (str, query) => [...str.split(query), query];
/*
1. we split the string into an array whenever query is found
2. we spread (...) the array into a new array
3. we add the query at the end of the new array
*/

var str = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
var query = "ipsum dolor";

const result = diff(str, query)

console.log(result)
console.log(result[0])
console.log(result[1])
console.log(result[2])
```

Comment: Always provide explanation in your answers.

Comment: Sry I posted the answer to fast. Just saw your updated question. The first question was easier to overread your requirements.

Comment: @Marvin the answer had comments in the code that explained each steps. Isn't this enough? Do I need outside of code text for a good answer in stackoverflow? If so I can stop adding comments in code and add the informations above the snippets. Thx for information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking is logically possible. a "string" can be a single letter, which is going to get very messy. at best maybe something like this?

```js
var str1 = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
var str2 = "ipsum dolor";
var parts = str1.split(str2); 

console.log(parts); // ['lorem ', ' sit amet']
```

Comment: Runnable Snippets are cool. They allow the asker to test your solution right away, you should use them

Comment: The requirement is to add the query as last entry in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the target string by the search string, and append the latter to the solution.

```js
const haystack = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
const needle = 'ipsum dolor';

const diff = (needle, haystack) =>
  [...haystack.split(needle), needle]

console.log(diff(needle,haystack));
// ["lorem ", " sit amet", "ipsum dolor"]
```